# Drawing a Recursive Graph

Tags: tikz-pgf

I think this question will have many downvotes as I don't know how to start and cannot provide enough source code. I am completely new to tikz and I would like to draw a recursive graph generated by complete graphs `$K_n$` to `$K_1$` as the figure shows. It started by `$K_7$` and `$K_6$` around it then `$K_5$` and so on until $K_1$. I did my best for weeks and still can achieve nothing. Here is the "code" I got so far.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\newcount\recurdepth
\newcount\bil
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)--(1,1);
\def\myrecur#1#2{
    \recurdepth=#2
    \ifnum\the\recurdepth>2\relax
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\batas}{#2-1}
        \begin{scope}[shift=(#1.north west)]
            \foreach \i in {0,...,\batas}{
                \advance\bil by 1
                \node[draw,circle] (v\i) at (\i*360/#2:1.4*\recurdepth){\i};
                \advance\recurdepth by-1\relax
                \myrecur{v\i}{\the\recurdepth};
            }
        \end{scope}
    \fi
}

\node[draw,circle,fill] (v0) at (0,0){};
\myrecur{v0}{5}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You should provide some details about the passage from n to n-1.  Otherwise, it looks more like a research problem than a TikZ question.

Comment: @DanielN, I can definitely use python and or MATLAB/OCTAVE to generate the graph. The picture I attached, I generated it using MATLAB in 2013.
The step is as follow: Draw ```$K_n$```, then make ```n``` copies of ```$K_{n-1}$``` and place the ```$K_{n-1}$``` such a way that every ```$K_{n-1}$``` is related to (for further step) each vertex of ```$K_n$```. Draw an edge from every vertex of ```$K_{n-1}$``` to the coresponding vertex of ```$K_n$```. Do the same steps until ```$K_1$```.

I just wonder if it is possible to draw such recursive/self-similar graphs with tikz, for a bigger scenario.

Answer (score 4):

This is more like a LaTeX3 solution. To draw this graph, you need to call the `\graph_recursive_draw:nnn` function. I have only tried up to N=7, which is already very slow. You can change the parameters to tweak the look of the graph.

The image below is generated with InkScape from the PDF file. It contained so much object that a bug might have occurred in InkScape. Therefore, it does not reflect what the PDF looks like.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{expl3}


\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \g_polygon_id_int
\int_gset:Nn \g_polygon_id_int {1}
\int_new:N \g_polygon_vertex_int
\int_gset:Nn \g_polygon_vertex_int {1}

\tl_new:N \l_graph_tmpa_tl
\tl_new:N \l_graph_tmpb_tl
\tl_new:N \l_graph_tmpc_tl
\tl_new:N \l_graph_tmpd_tl
\tl_new:N \l_graph_tmpe_tl
\tl_new:N \l_graph_tmpf_tl

\int_new:N \l_graph_tmpa_int
\int_new:N \l_graph_tmpb_int

\fp_new:N \l_graph_tmpa_fp
\fp_new:N \l_graph_tmpb_fp
\fp_new:N \l_graph_tmpc_fp
\fp_new:N \l_graph_tmpd_fp
\fp_new:N \l_graph_tmpe_fp
\fp_new:N \l_graph_tmpf_fp
\fp_new:N \l_graph_tmpg_fp

% defines how much the side length shrinks between levels
\fp_new:N \g_graph_radius_shrink_fp
\fp_gset:Nn \g_graph_radius_shrink_fp {0.3}
% defines the distance between levels
% it is measured in multiples of radius
\fp_new:N \g_graph_distance_fp
\fp_gset:Nn \g_graph_distance_fp {5.5}
% defines how much the distance shrinks between levels
\fp_new:N \g_graph_distance_shrink_fp
\fp_gset:Nn \g_graph_distance_shrink_fp {0.5}
% defines how much the line width shrinks between levels
\fp_new:N \g_graph_line_width_shrink_fp
\fp_gset:Nn \g_graph_line_width_shrink_fp {0.6}

\cs_set:Npn \graph_polygon_param_csname:n #1 {
    __g_polygon_param_\int_to_alph:n {#1}_tl
}


\tl_new:N \l_graph_x_tl
\tl_new:N \l_graph_y_tl
% extract x, y coordiantes from a TikZ coordinate
% #1: coordinate name
\cs_set:Npn \graph_extract_xy:n #1 {
    \path (#1);
    \pgfgetlastxy{\l_graph_x_tl}{\l_graph_y_tl};
    % unit conversion (in cm)
    \tl_set:Nx \l_graph_x_tl {\dim_to_decimal_in_unit:nn {\l_graph_x_tl} {1cm}}
    \tl_set:Nx \l_graph_y_tl {\dim_to_decimal_in_unit:nn {\l_graph_y_tl} {1cm}}
}

% define a polygon
% the polygon id is given by the value of \g_polygon_id_int before function call
% the parameter of each polygon would be saved in the command name generated by \graph_polygon_param_csname:n
% #1: number of sides
% #2: center x
% #3: center y
% #4: radius
% #5: rotation
\cs_set:Npn \graph_define_polygon:nnnnn #1#2#3#4#5 {
    % save parameters
    \tl_new:c {\graph_polygon_param_csname:n {\g_polygon_id_int}}
    \tl_gset:cx {\graph_polygon_param_csname:n {\g_polygon_id_int}} {
        {#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}
    }
    % save starting vertex index
    \tl_gput_right:cx {\graph_polygon_param_csname:n {\g_polygon_id_int}} {
        {\int_use:N \g_polygon_vertex_int}
    }
    % define coordinates
    \int_step_inline:nnn {0} {#1 - 1} {
        \coordinate (vertex-\int_use:N \g_polygon_vertex_int) at (
            \fp_eval:n {(#4) * cos((##1/#1) * 2 * \c_pi_fp + 0.5 * \c_pi_fp + (#5)) + #2},
            \fp_eval:n {(#4) * sin((##1/#1) * 2 * \c_pi_fp + 0.5 * \c_pi_fp + (#5)) + #3}
        );
        \int_gincr:N \g_polygon_vertex_int
    }
    \int_gincr:N \g_polygon_id_int
}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \graph_define_polygon:nnnnn {xxxxx}

% define the subpolygon of a polygon given id
% the number of subpolygons would depend on the number of sides of the given polygon
% new polygons are defined using \graph_define_polygon:nnnnn
% #1: polygon id
\cs_set:Npn \graph_define_subpolygon:n #1 {
    % get number of sides
    \int_set:Nn \l_graph_tmpa_int {\tl_item:cn {\graph_polygon_param_csname:n {#1}} {1}}
    % get center position
    \fp_set:Nn \l_graph_tmpa_fp {\tl_item:cn {\graph_polygon_param_csname:n {#1}} {2}}
    \fp_set:Nn \l_graph_tmpb_fp {\tl_item:cn {\graph_polygon_param_csname:n {#1}} {3}}
    % get radius
    \fp_set:Nn \l_graph_tmpc_fp {\tl_item:cn {\graph_polygon_param_csname:n {#1}} {4}}
    % compute new radius
    \fp_set:Nn \l_graph_tmpd_fp {\l_graph_tmpc_fp * \g_graph_radius_shrink_fp}
    % compute new distance factor
    \fp_set:Nn \l_graph_tmpe_fp {\g_graph_distance_fp * \g_graph_distance_shrink_fp}
    % get rotation angle
    \fp_set:Nn \l_graph_tmpf_fp {\tl_item:cn {\graph_polygon_param_csname:n {#1}} {5}}
    
    % compute new rotation angle offset
    \int_compare:nNnTF {\l_graph_tmpa_int} = {4} {
        \fp_set:Nn \l_graph_tmpg_fp {\l_graph_tmpf_fp}
    } {
        \fp_set:Nn \l_graph_tmpg_fp {
            \l_graph_tmpf_fp + \c_pi_fp / (\l_graph_tmpa_int - 1)
        }
    }
    
    % get vertex strating index
    \tl_set:Nx \l_graph_tmpa_tl {\tl_item:cn {\graph_polygon_param_csname:n {#1}} {6}}
    
    % define new polygons
    \int_step_inline:nnn {0} {\l_graph_tmpa_int - 1} {
        % acquire position of this vertex
        \exp_args:Nx \graph_extract_xy:n {vertex-\int_eval:n {\l_graph_tmpa_tl + ##1}}
        \graph_define_polygon:xxxxx
            {\int_eval:n {\l_graph_tmpa_int - 1}}
            {\fp_eval:n {\l_graph_tmpa_fp + ((\l_graph_x_tl) - (\l_graph_tmpa_fp)) * \l_graph_tmpe_fp}}
            {\fp_eval:n {\l_graph_tmpb_fp + ((\l_graph_y_tl) - (\l_graph_tmpb_fp)) * \l_graph_tmpe_fp}}
            {\fp_use:N \l_graph_tmpd_fp}
            {\fp_eval:n {
                    \l_graph_tmpg_fp + 2 * \c_pi_fp * (##1) / \l_graph_tmpa_int
                }
            }
    }
}

% draw the polygon
% #1: polygon id
\cs_set:Npn \graph_draw_polygon:n #1 {
    % get number of sides
    \tl_set:Nx \l_graph_tmpa_tl {\tl_item:cn {\graph_polygon_param_csname:n {#1}} {1}}
    % get vertex strating index
    \tl_set:Nx \l_graph_tmpb_tl {\tl_item:cn {\graph_polygon_param_csname:n {#1}} {6}}
    
    % connect lines
    \int_step_variable:nnNn {\l_graph_tmpb_tl} {\l_graph_tmpb_tl + \l_graph_tmpa_tl - 1} \l_graph_tmpc_tl {
        \int_step_variable:nnNn {\l_graph_tmpb_tl} {\l_graph_tmpb_tl + \l_graph_tmpa_tl - 1} \l_graph_tmpd_tl {
            \int_compare:nNnT {\l_graph_tmpd_tl} > {\l_graph_tmpc_tl} {
                \draw[line~width=\g_cur_linewidth_dim] (vertex-\l_graph_tmpd_tl) -- (vertex-\l_graph_tmpc_tl);
            }
        }
    }
}


% connect the vertices of a polygon and its subpolygon
% #1: polygon id
% #1: starting id of subpolygons
\cs_set:Npn \graph_connect_subpolygon:nn #1#2 {
    % get vertex strating index of main polygon
    \tl_set:Nx \l_graph_tmpa_tl {\tl_item:cn {\graph_polygon_param_csname:n {#1}} {6}}
    % get number of sides
    \tl_set:Nx \l_graph_tmpb_tl {\tl_item:cn {\graph_polygon_param_csname:n {#1}} {1}}
    \int_step_variable:nnNn {\l_graph_tmpa_tl} {\l_graph_tmpa_tl + \l_graph_tmpb_tl - 1} \l_graph_tmpc_tl {
        % get number of sides of corresponding subpolygon
        \tl_set:Nx \l_graph_tmpd_tl {
            \tl_item:cn {\graph_polygon_param_csname:n {#2 + \l_graph_tmpc_tl - \l_graph_tmpa_tl}} {1}
        }
        % get starting index of corresponding subpolygon
        \tl_set:Nx \l_graph_tmpe_tl {
            \tl_item:cn {\graph_polygon_param_csname:n {#2 + \l_graph_tmpc_tl - \l_graph_tmpa_tl}} {6}
        }
        \int_step_variable:nnNn {\l_graph_tmpe_tl} {\l_graph_tmpe_tl + \l_graph_tmpd_tl - 1} \l_graph_tmpf_tl {
            \draw[line~width=\g_cur_linewidth_dim] (vertex-\l_graph_tmpc_tl) -- (vertex-\l_graph_tmpf_tl);
        }
    }
}


\tl_new:N \l_resursive_tmpa_tl
\tl_new:N \l_resursive_tmpb_tl
\tl_new:N \l_resursive_tmpc_tl
\tl_new:N \l_resursive_tmpd_tl
\dim_new:N \g_cur_linewidth_dim

% a recursive function to draw the graph
% #1: polygon index
\cs_set:Npn \__graph_recursive_draw:n #1 {
    % use a group to protect local variables across recursive calls
    \group_begin:
        % get number of sides
        \tl_set:Nx \l_resursive_tmpa_tl {\tl_item:cn {\graph_polygon_param_csname:n {#1}} {1}}
        \int_compare:nNnT {\l_resursive_tmpa_tl} > {3} {
            % save starting polygon index
            \tl_set:Nx \l_resursive_tmpb_tl {\int_use:N \g_polygon_id_int}
            % generate subpolygons for this polygon
            \graph_define_subpolygon:n {#1}
            % draw subpolygons and connect them
            \int_step_inline:nnn {\l_resursive_tmpb_tl} {\l_resursive_tmpb_tl + \l_resursive_tmpa_tl - 1} {
                \graph_draw_polygon:n {##1}
            }
            \exp_args:NnV \graph_connect_subpolygon:nn {#1} \l_resursive_tmpb_tl
            % reduce line width
            \dim_gset:Nn \g_cur_linewidth_dim {
                \fp_use:N\g_graph_line_width_shrink_fp \g_cur_linewidth_dim
            }
            % call this function recursively for each subpolygon
            \int_step_inline:nnn {\l_resursive_tmpb_tl} {\l_resursive_tmpb_tl + \l_resursive_tmpa_tl - 1} {
                \__graph_recursive_draw:n {##1}
            }
        }
    \group_end:
}

% a recursive function to draw the graph (user version)
% #1: number of sides
% #2: starting radius
% #3: starting line width
\cs_set:Npn \graph_recursive_draw:nnn #1#2#3 {
    \dim_gset:Nn \g_cur_linewidth_dim {#3}
    % define a new polygon
    \graph_define_polygon:nnnnn {#1}{0}{0}{#2}{0}
    % draw the polygon
    \exp_args:Nx \graph_draw_polygon:n {\int_eval:n {\g_polygon_id_int - 1}}
    % call recursive draw
    \exp_args:Nx \__graph_recursive_draw:n {\int_eval:n {\g_polygon_id_int - 1}}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \graph_recursive_draw:nnn {7}{2}{0.8pt}
\end{tikzpicture}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

(Edit: I just realized that the rotation of small polygons is off by 180 degrees. May fix it when I have time.)

Answer (score 3):

[image]

The figure above is the result of the recursion that descends 5 steps only, from 7 to 3.  It takes 30 seconds for compilation.  (I don't have the courage to go to 2). I know that the drawing is not exactly what you are looking for, but it is easy to add the missing strings (see below).

- The program is based on a decoration (called `descending`) that creates the recursion. It has three arguments: the number of vertices of the polygon, the step of the recursion, and the bound (maximal number of steps).
- If you comment out the first `for` loop, you can see the graphical structure of the recursion.
  [image]
- Of course, you can change `\draw` into `\path` when the strings are constructed (to be able to call the decoration) and obtain the following image.
  [image]
- As for the strings that appear in your question, if you really need them, you can construct them in a loop similar to the first one.  For the current vertex of the regular polygon at step *n* (say with *m* vertices), you need to consider all the vertices of the next polygon attached to it with *m-1* vertices.

**The code**

```
\documentclass[11pt, margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math, calc, decorations.markings}
\begin{document}

\tikzmath{
  real \r, \da;
  \r = 3;
}
\tikzset{
  descending/.style n args={3}{%
    decoration={markings,
      mark=at position 1 with {
        code={
          \tikzmath{
            \da = 180/(#1);
            \c = \r*pow(.33, #2);
            for \i in {0, ..., #1}{
              {
                \draw[black, thick]
                ({\i*360/(#1)+\da}: \c/2) -- ({(\i+1)*360/(#1)+\da}: \c/2);
              };
            };  
            for \i in {1, ..., #1}{
              if #2<#3 then {
                {
                  \path[gray, thin, descending={#1-1}{#2+1}{#3}]
                  (0, 0) -- ({\i*360/(#1)+\da}: \c);
                };
              } else {
                {
                  \draw[]
                  (0, 0) -- ({\i*360/(#1)+\da}: {\r*pow(.33, #2)});
                };
              };
            };
          }
        }
      }
    },
    postaction=decorate
  } 
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[descending={7}{0}{4}] (0, 0) -- (0.1, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```