# Can I collect all the code in one code?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, foreach, loops

I want to write a single code for many polygons using foreach. How can I plot each one with the same code by using n variables and writing n values? I am repeating a few steps in the same way as below. But I want to write a single code for each polygon, usually foreach loop is used, but I would like to learn different loops. I'm working on one detail, tikz.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{caption}

\tikzset{
    buffer/.style={
        draw,
        regular polygon,
        regular polygon sides=4,
        minimum size=20em
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[buffer, fill=pink]{};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{One square}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[buffer, fill=pink] (A) {};
        \foreach \mycorner in {1,2,3,4}
            {\node[buffer, fill=green,scale=.33, transform shape] (A\mycorner) at (A.corner \mycorner) {};} 
    \end{tikzpicture}       
    \caption{One square with squares}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use different loops? What exactly do you mean? Usually `\foreach` is able to do way more than the standard user needs, what exactly are you missing from it?

Comment: Sounds like you want something recursive... I don't think it's a good idea, as TeX is not very fast that you can't exceed a few layers anyway. Just copy and paste manually. If you still insist, use LuaTeX and write Lua code that generates TeX code.

Comment: I would love to use foreach, but I couldn't write the code I wanted. I wanted to say that I am open to different alternatives. It would be more convenient for me to write it with foreach. @Skillmon

Comment: Then what exactly do you want? You didn't describe it.

Comment: yes I want something recursive. actually I'm looing for a common code for each polygon, which will only take a few steps. @user202729

Comment: Not specific at all. Describe clearly by [edit]ing the question. (anyway, as I said above, that's not really a good idea as code in TeX is hard to read, just write out theed nested foreach loops by hand or use LuaTeX)

Comment: Does these help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/597789/1952 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/222881/1952

Comment: Do you mean parametrize this construction with respect the number of sides of the polygon?

Comment: yes i want to do that @vi pa

Answer (score 1):

Parametrize this construction with respect to the number of side is easy with a `\newcommand`. This is my attempt.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{caption}

\tikzset{
    buffer/.style={
        draw,
        regular polygon,
        regular polygon sides=#1,
        minimum size=20em
    }
}

\newcommand{\myPoly}[1]{\node[buffer=#1, fill=pink] (A) {};
    \foreach \mycorner in {1,2,...,#1}
    {\node[buffer=#1, fill=green,scale=.33, transform shape] (A\mycorner) at (A.corner \mycorner) {};} }

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[buffer=4, fill=pink]{};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{One square}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\myPoly{5} 
    \end{tikzpicture}       
    \caption{One pentagon with pentagons}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: One pentagon with pentagons]

Comment: thank you I will continue to improve on this, it helped a lot @vi pa